# Confluent Platform in Windows

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Is it possible to run complete Confluent Platform on Windows ? 
If not what is preferable way to run Confluent platform ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Per [list of supported operating systems](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#operating-systems):

> Windows is not currently supported. Windows users can download and use the ZIP and TAR archives, but must run the JAR files directly.

You could also [use Docker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp.html#docker) to run it.

Comment: I do not have facility to install Docker using my current laptop. We don't have virtualization enabled. I was able to get Kafka server, broker and produce, consumer running through Windows. I want to use ksql server and ksql-cli. Is there any documentation I can refer to run in Windows. I don't want to run complete confluent package.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Docker on Windows 10 Pro you can [install Confluent Platform on Windows 10  Subsystem for Linux](https://nielsberglund.com/2018/07/10/install-confluent-platform-kafka-on-windows/)