# confluent CLI - windows environment

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am exploring to see if we could run confluent on windows. As per the following articles, it seems windows is not supported.

> https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html#operating-systems
> [Confluent Platform in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143458/confluent-platform-in-windows)

However, when I look at confluent CLI, windows seems to be supported

> https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html#tarball-installation

But again, there is a phrase here about windows is not being supported.

> On non-Windows platforms, the Confluent CLI offers confluent local commands (designed to operate on a local install of Confluent Platform) which require Java, and JDK version 1.8 or 1.11 is recommended. If you have multiple versions of Java installed, set JAVA_HOME to the version you want Confluent Platform to use.

So, the questions are

- Is windows supported, as per latest ? ( I doubt it is not ?)
- What is the CLI that is being supported for windows ? For what it
  could be used for ?
- It also seems windows is NOT supported for *local* development perspective as well ? ( I mean is it possible to issue "confluent local" commands ?

PS : Please give inputs without referring to virtualized environments such as Docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right windows is not supported.
The CLI you get for windows is only to manage and retrieve metadata for the remote confluent platform. First, you will have to log in to confluent by issuing command `confluent.exe login --url <url>`.
More info at [confluent-login](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/command-reference/confluent_login.html#confluent-login).
Following are the commands you get with confluent windows distribution:

```
Available Commands:
audit-log       Manage audit log configuration.
cluster         Retrieve metadata about Confluent Platform clusters.
completion      Print shell completion code.
connect         Manage Connect.
help            Help about any command
iam             Manage RBAC, ACL and IAM permissions.
kafka           Manage Apache Kafka.
ksql            Manage ksqlDB applications.
login           Log in to Confluent Platform (required for RBAC).
logout          Log out of Confluent Platform.
schema-registry Manage Schema Registry.
secret          Manage secrets for Confluent Platform.
update          Update the Confluent CLI.
version         Print the Confluent CLI version.
```

And windows is also not supported for local development. You can't issue confluent commands like `confluent local`

Comment: Not agree: on WSL you got confluent local set of commands that can start/stop and manage your local standalone installation. It's not intended for production use but for POC and trial it's good alternative. https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/local/confluent_local_current.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same challenge. I got Confluent Platform on Docker/Windows 10 machine nad wany to access CLI using WSL as stated here:

`https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html`

The issue is that when running commands in ubuntu terminal I get `unknown command` when triggering `confluent`.

Answer (score 0):

Confluent CLI are facade for local installation of confluent variants of Kafka, were with local command you can manage your local installation.
Look here : [Confluent CLI local documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/confluent-cli/current/command-reference/local/confluent_local_current.html)

It assumes that you got the product installed locally. I had installed by following this page [Confluent Ubuntu local installation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html) and got all components working, well almost.

So it can work on Windows 10 but throw WSL only. There are some explanations how to install Kafka on Windows, but hole idea behind Confluent is to use Confluent Cloud for production environments.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download the Confluent CLI from the location https://github.com/confluentinc/cli/releases/tag/v3.53.0

Once the appropriate version as per your local OS version is downloaded and unzipped, in my case I was able to successfully launch the confluent.exe from windows 10 cmd.exe and execute the CLI commands